# Finding physical path on iis via power Shell

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to find and store an IIS site physical path to a variable , however the shown result has so many lines, is it possible to just store  "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" in a variable like $Directory in the following lines?

#### MY COMMAND

```
$Site = Get-IISSite "Default Web Site"
$Site
```

###RESULT

```
Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings                                                                                                                      
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------                                                                                                                      
Default Web Site 1    Started    **C:\inetpub\wwwroot**             http *:80:                                                                                                                    
                                                                http 192.168.97.7:80:                                                                                                         
                                                                net.tcp 808:*                                                                                                                 
                                                                net.msmq localhost                                                                                                            
                                                                msmq.formatname localhost                                                                                                     
                                                                net.pipe *
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code from Pba even shorter you can use the "dot notation" to expand the attributes you're after:

```
$Directory = 
    Get-IISSite "Default Web Site" | 
    Foreach-Object {$_.Applications.VirtualDirectories.PhysicalPath}
$Directory
```

This way it's even easier to actually see the relations of the attributes.

Comment: Even shorter, no foreach necessary: `(Get-IISSite "Default Web Site").Applications.VirtualDirectories.PhysicalPath`

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the expected result

Written out version:

```
$Directory = Get-IISSite "Default Web Site" | Foreach-Object {$_.Applications} | Foreach-Object {$_.VirtualDirectories} | Foreach-Object {$_.PhysicalPath}
```

Alias version for slighty shorter code (Less readable, so not recommended)

```
$Directory = Get-IISSite "Default Web Site" | % {$_.Applications} | % {$_.VirtualDirectories} | % {$_.PhysicalPath}
```

This loops through IIS and returns the working directories. Be aware that you will get more results when you start using applications or virtual directories, so in that case you need to fiddle around with the foreach loops a bit.

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid aliasses and on the other hand using indentation to make your code more readable. ;-)

Comment: True! I'll edit the answer with a more writting out statement!